# Troubleshooting React versions: Is it O.K. to simply change the package.json file?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I think that when I upgraded to React 18, React broke a part of my app.  I wanted to verify this behavior by simply using my previous package.json file which I saved as package-previous.json.

I'm assuming webpack allows one to simply change the package.json file to restore a previous app configuration, but I wanted to make sure there are no caveats.

I'm going back from:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6"
  },
```

to:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6"
  },
```

Comment: It is generally okay to change the package.json file to switch between different versions of React, as long as you make sure that the versions of React and any other related packages are compatible with each other. You can use the npm install command with the -f or --force flag to force npm to use the versions specified in your package.json file, even if those versions are already installed.

Comment: So, I need to run `npm install -f` after I update it?  Otherwise it won't use versions specified.  Is there documentation on how this works exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with updating the dependency versions in your package.json; if the dependencies you changed are already installed, you can run `npm update` to upgrade or downgrade their versions, otherwise, you should run `npm install`.

This will update your `node_modules` and your `package-lock.json` files.

Comment: Is there any difference between running npm install and npm update after I moved the package.json file?  What does the -f flag do?

Comment: `npm update` will update all of the unlocked dependencies (ones that contain the "^" sign before their version) to their latest version, it will also change versions of manually updated dependency versions, like in your use-case.